# CSS bug with transition on opacity, blur, and over-flow hidden on parent

Tags: javascript, css, transition, opacity, blur

I wrote an simple function which implements opacity on a blurred image on mouseover.
Note that parent is smaller than child(image), I need over-flow hidden.
You can see a bug, at the end of transition, the image size changes suddenly!

the problem disappears if I delete transition, (but I want transition)
the problem disappears if I supp blur (but I want blur)
the problem disappears if parent is bigger than child (but I want parent smaller with over-flow hidden)
there is a accumulation of parameter (opacity-transition, blur, overflow hidden on parent) which creates a bug, and I don't know how to fix it.

```js
var my_parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var my_child = document.querySelector('.child');

my_parent.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  my_child.style.opacity = '1';

  // SAME PROBLEM WITH ANIMATION
  // my_child.style.animationName = 'my_animation';   
  // my_child.style.animationDuration = '1s';
  // my_child.style.animationTimingFunction = 'ease-in-out';
  // my_child.style.animationIterationCount = 'linear';
  // my_child.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
  // my_child.style.animationFillMode = 'forwards';
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-filter: blur(40px);
  -o-filter: blur(40px);
  -ms-filter: blur(40px);
  filter: blur(40px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes my_animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Transition are to show a delay in properties change , same as for animation . As you are defining `height` & `width` so this delay appears in them too it's not a bug . You can use `transition: 0.5s opacity` to show only for opacity

Comment: i understand but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: works fine in FF